# Deploy rails docker app with drone CI (using docker-compose)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, deployment, devops, drone.io

Although it could be a silly question! but I can't find better solution so posting here.

There is existing old rails project with following detials:

- Repository of on **Gitlab**
- Using **drone CI** & **Capistrano** (already functional and doing deployments with CI)
- Target server is our own server

We want to dockerize our rails app! So, Added Dockerfile and docker-compose files in project & using **db from host machine**. Project is working fine at local

**Want to run this dockerize rails app in CI and deploy to target ENV (Staging, UAT, Production etc)?**

***Note:*** We have our own server to save docker images. Plus we don't wanna use `sh` scripts for the deployment.
*I think using docker & drone CI, Capistrano will be removed!*